# Multiple has_one association to one polymorphic model

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, activerecord

I have two models, `Address` and `User`:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :contact_address, class_name: "Address", as: :resource
  has_one :billing_address, class_name: "Address", as: :resource
end
```

Problem is if I create `billing_address` for `User` it will be automatically set as `contact_address`, since the `addresses` table doesn't specify a different `resource_type` (both are `User`).
Can you give me some advice on how I should set up my models?

Thanks

Comment: From what i have understood, You don't need do polymorphic associations. You can just do something like, user has_many :contact_address and have a flag in the address table to denote whether that address is a billing address as well or just a contact address. I can elaborate more, if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, this could be a way, but i need this to be polymorphic association :(

Comment: The current schema would not work in any case whether you use polymorphic or not...now if you not used the polymorphic association, then again the problem would persist becoz the SQL query that would be fired in the backend would be same becoz you have specified the same resource and class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I choose easy way, added another foreign_key for `addresses` table. After that:

```
has_one :contact_address, class_name: "Address", as: :resource, foreign_key: :foreign_key
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say a billing address is more to do with an order than a person. For example, on one order I might want you to bill me at work, another at home.

Also, a person can have many addresses, but an address can also have many people. It is a network, not a hierarchy. The classic representation:

```
PARTY
id
type
name

PARTY_ADDRESS
id
party_id
address_id
type {home, work}

ADDRESS
id
suite
...

ORDER
id
date
customer_party_address_id
bill_to_party_address_id

ORDER_ITEM
id
order_id
product_id
price
quantity
ship_to_party_address_id
```

Answer (score 0):

[Single table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) can help you out. To get this to work you have to add a `type` column to the `locations` table through a migration (as you do with all Single Table Inheritance models).

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true
end

class ContactAddress < Address
end

class BillingAddress < Address
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :contact_address, as: :resource
  has_one :billing_address, as: :resource
end
```

For what it's worth, the `belongs_to` relationship name (`:resource`) is  a bit weird. Maybe `:addressable` would make more sense?